# How do I pass a value from array for every increment of score

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in SpriteKit and I have a variable `score` which is `NSInteger()` and `passed` which is `SKLabelNode`

My `score` score increases for every hurdle the user passes, how can I send a value from array for every increment the `score` makes.

This is the array, and it will have 42 items

```
var passed2 = ["English", "Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"]
```

I'm doing it in a very lengthy way, like this:

```
if score==1{
   passed.text="English"
}

else if score==2{
   passed.text="Maths"
}
```

How can I pass the value from array one at a time with every score increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name your array and your label the same thing it's super confusing. I hope this is helpful.

```
passed.text=passed2[score] // value in array passed at index score
```

Reset when out of index (when score more than indexes in array).

```
if (score == passed2.count) {
    score = 0
}
```

Comment: the label is `passed` and the array is `passed2`

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps

```
if(currentScore != score) {
    passed.text = passed[score-1];
}
    // where currentScore variable maintains score from earlier iteration
```

Comment: No matter how simpler your solution is, you should always explain what have you done it it.